# I can't get redirected to my update page in Spring Boot 3 using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having the problem ***An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/update-customer.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/update-customer.html]")***, i can not be redirected to
my `ùpdate-customer.html` because this problem.

- `list.html`

```
  <td>
     <a th:href="@{'/customers/form-update-customer/' + ${customer.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</a>
  </td>
```

- `CustomerController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

  private CustomerService customerService;

  public CustomerController(CustomerService theCostumerService){
        customerService = theCostumerService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/form-update-customer/{id}")
    public String formUpdateCustomer(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
      CostumerModel costumerModel = customerService.read(id);
      model.addAttribute("customer", customerModel);
      return "update-customer";
  }

}
```

- `update-customer.html`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/bootstrap-5.3.3.min.css}">
        <script th:src="@{/assets/bootstrap-5.3.3.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/assets/jquery-3.7.1.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/assets/mask.js}"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Update Customer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form th:action="@{'/customers/update-costumer/' + *{id}}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control mb-4 w-25" placeholder="Input the name"/>
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" class="text-danger"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Update</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I guess that `Update` button is right, return me `localhost:8080/customers/form-update-customer/8`.

Comment: The error message is about parsing file `templates/update-customer.html`. Please share it, if you want us to help you.

Comment: @Mar-Z i insert ```update-customer.html``` in ```templates``` and in my question.

Comment: Please show us the complete stack trace. My guess is that it doesn't like your form declaration as you are not providing ```th:object="${customer}"```. Also, your post action should be ```th:action="@{/customers/update-costumer/{id}(id = ${customer.id})}"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form tag in `update-customer.html` should be either:

```html
<form th:action="@{'/customers/update-costumer/' + ${customer.id}}"
    th:object="${customer}" method="POST">
```

or

```html
<form th:action="@{/customers/update-costumer/{id}(id = ${customer.id})}"
    th:object="${customer}" method="POST">
```

Both are valid. The crucial point is `th:object="${customer}"` where you bind the model variable `customer`, added in the controller, to the form data object model (DOM). After doing it, you can access the object properties like this:

```
${customer.id}
```

or

```
*{name}
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not see my wrong in tag ```<form>```.